# Highcharts crash after adding tickpositioner

Tags: javascript, highcharts, crash

I have a bug in my Highchart axis, when deselecting all products is crashes and the page needs to reload.

The code can be viewed here:  http://jsfiddle.net/8g5sonpp/18/

The crash happened after I added this code:

```
           tickPositioner: function () {
            var positions = [],
                tick = Math.floor(this.dataMin),
                increment = Math.ceil((this.dataMax - this.dataMin) / 6);

            for (tick; tick - increment <= this.dataMax; tick += increment) {
                positions.push(tick);
            }
            return positions;
        },
```

I added it to avoid the y-axis showing minus/negative numbers. But the result is a crash when all series are deselected.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the condidition which check if dataMin / dataMax are not undefined.

```
tickPositioner: function () {
            var positions = [];

                if(this.dataMin!== UNDEFINED && this.dataMax!== UNDEFINED) {
                var tick = Math.floor(this.dataMin),
                increment = Math.ceil((this.dataMax - this.dataMin) / 6);

            for (tick; tick - increment <= this.dataMax; tick += increment) {
                positions.push(tick);
            }
                }
            return positions;
        },
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/8g5sonpp/24/